# Unittest in Python 2 not working in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tdd, python-unittest

To have some practice and work on my programming skills I decided to built an application in Python to solve problems from Project Euler. I have no experience with unit testing so I decided to build my project with the help of  TDD and get some experience with that as well. Unfortunately while building the foundation I run my program with Python3 but did all the unit testing with Python2. Now I try to do the test with Python3 and it fails.

Before this I never wrote more than some small scripts with Python. I expect this project to be bigger and also it will contain more files so after some research I decided to use the following project structure:

```
project_euler:
  euler:
    - __init__.py
    - euler.py
    - problems.py
  tests:
    - __init__.py
    - test_euler.py
    - test_problems.py
```

The init files are empty.

**euler.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8


class Euler:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**problems.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import euler


class ProjectEuler(euler.Euler):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**test_euler.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import unittest
import euler.euler as euler


class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # a bunch of tests here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(module=None)
```

test_problems.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import unittest
from euler import problems


class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # a bunch of tests here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(module=None)
```

The following commands do work:
python -m unittest discover
python -m unittest tests.test_problems

The following do not.
**python3 -m unittest discover**

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_problems
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/me/code/project_euler/tests/test_problems.py", line 5, in <module>
    import euler.problems as problems
  File "/home/me/code/project_euler/euler/problems.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ProjectEuler(euler.Euler):
AttributeError: module 'euler' has no attribute 'Euler'
```

**python3 -m unittest tests.test_problems**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 141, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 148, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/me/code/project_euler/tests/test_problems.py", line 5, in <module>
    import euler.problems as problems
  File "/home/mvrakking/code/project_euler/euler/problems.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ProjectEuler(euler.Euler):
AttributeError: module 'euler' has no attribute 'Euler'
```

I tried all kinds of options, but it breaks my program or my unit test. I can't find what is the difference between Python 2.7.13 and 3.6.2 that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is in a file **problems.py** in row `import euler`. Try to replace it on `from .euler import Euler`

Comment: That gives the following message when I run the program: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.euler'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: try to add `__init__` in main

Comment: Anyway, problem is n this row, it depends on structure and settings

Comment: I have no file main. Also I tried several things with this row, but it breaks the program or the unit test.

Comment: Do you use some IDE?

Comment: No, I use Atom and run the code from the command line. Working on Fedora 26.

Comment: Try to replace `unittest.main(module=None)` on `unittest.main()`

Comment: I used now 
try:
    from .euler import Euler
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from euler import Euler

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but it works. And probably falls under 'ask forgiveness, not permission'.